# Can I have two varchar types next to each other?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create schemas in SQL but I am running into issues with my variable types. When I have two varchar types I run into errors but if I only have one type as a varchar my code can execute. What am I doing wrong?

My code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer(
  user_id integer 
  ccnum integer
  expdate timestamptz
  name varchar(30) 
  email varchar(100)
 );
```

Error

```
Error: near line 8: in prepare, near "email": syntax error (1)

[Execution complete with exit code 1]
```

Comment: you are missing a lot of commas see https://dbfiddle.uk/6JdUDxyv

Comment: Each field definition should have a comma after it except for the last one. So I don't see how that `CREATE TABLE` works at all. It is spelled out in the docs [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). Look at *Examples* section.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing commas.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer(
  user_id integer,
  ccnum integer,
  expdate timestamptz,
  name varchar(30),
  email varchar(100)
 );
```